# How to copy a list of class from one script to another containing the same class within

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ScriptA

```
public class ScriptA: MonoBehaviour{

public List<LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;

[System.Serializable]
public class LootItemsList
{
    public GameObject _lootItem;
    public Vector3 _lootItemOrigin;
    public float _lootColliderActivationTime = 0.5f;
}}
```

ScriptB

```
 public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour{

public List<LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;

[System.Serializable]
public class LootItemsList
{
    public GameObject _lootItem;
    public Vector3 _lootItemOrigin;
    public float _lootColliderActivationTime = 0.5f;
}

void Start(){
ScriptA scriptA = ObjA.GetComponent<ScriptA>();
    _lootItemsListToUse = scriptA._lootItemsListToUse;
}}
```

I get this error :
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ScriptB.LootItemsList>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ScriptA.LootItemsList>'

I also tried this

```
_lootItemsListToUse  = new List<ScriptA.LootItemsList>((IEnumerable<ScriptA.LootItemsList>)script._lootItemsList);
```

no error in MS studio but I get this error on play :
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
(wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)

Please can someone help me with the correct way to copy this list? thanks

Comment: I guess a correct way of picking up all items would be to move items from one list to another. One by one.

Comment: why are you nesting twice `LootItemsList` in different classes instead of having it as separate class?

Comment: In C#, even if two classes have exactly the same properties and have the same class name, they are not the same class. To the compiler they are different types, residing in different namespaces. For the compiler assigning a `ScriptA.LootItemsList` to a `ScriptB.LootItemsList` is like say assigning a `string` to an `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two types - just because they happen to have the same name and field names - are in no way related. They are completely different types.

---

The most obvious answer would be: Don't implement it twice. Rather reference it accordingly

ScriptA.cs

```
public class ScriptA: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class LootItemsList
    {
        public GameObject _lootItem;
        public Vector3 _lootItemOrigin;
        public float _lootColliderActivationTime = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

ScriptB.cs

```
public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ScriptA.LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;
    
    void Start()
    {
        ScriptA scriptA = ObjA.GetComponent<ScriptA>();
        _lootItemsListToUse = scriptA._lootItemsListToUse;
    }
}
```

---

Or even: Don't nest that class under another at all but have a third script in outer scope

LootItemList.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LootItemsList
{
    public GameObject _lootItem;
    public Vector3 _lootItemOrigin;
    public float _lootColliderActivationTime = 0.5f;
}
```

ScriptA.cs

```
public class ScriptA: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;
}
```

ScriptB.cs

```
public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<LootItemsList> _lootItemsListToUse;
    
    void Start()
    {
        ScriptA scriptA = ObjA.GetComponent<ScriptA>();
        _lootItemsListToUse = scriptA._lootItemsListToUse;
    }
}
```